# Collatz Conjecture: Understanding why for a given $K, L$, there are only a finite number of solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, matrix-equations, collatz-conjecture

I am reading through this [paper](https://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B35%5DSidW-3n+1-ActaArith%5B2005%5D.pdf) by
by Simon & Weger regarding the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

I am stuck on the reasoning at the end of 2.2

**Let**:

- $n$ be a natural number.
- $T(n) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2}(3n + 1), && \text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
  \frac{1}{2}n, && \text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
  \end{cases}$
- *sequence* be an increasing subsequence of odd integers followed by a decreasing subsequence of even integers
- a *cycle* be an $m$-*cycle* if it consists of $m$ sequences with a total of $K$ odd numbers and a total of $L$ even numbers.
- a sequence is *periodic* if there exists an integer $p \ge 1$ in the sequence $\{ n, T(n), T^2(n), \dots, T^{p}(n) \}$ where:

  - $T^0(n) = n$
  - $T^{i+1}(n) = T(T^i(n))$
  - $T^p(n) = n$
- $t_0, t_1, \dots, t_{m-1}$ be the indices of the $m$ local minima in an $m$-cycle such that:

  - $t_0 = 0$
  - $t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < \dots < t_{m-1} < p$
- $s_0, s_1, \dots, s_{m-1}$ be the indices of the $m$ local maxima in an $m$-cycle such that:

  - $t_0 < s_0 < t_1 < s_1 < \dots < t_{m-1} < s_{m-1} \le p-1$
- $x_i, y_i$ be the values of the local minima and maxima so that:

  - $x_i = T^{t_i}(n)$
  - $y_i = T^{s_i}(n)$
- $k_i, l_i$ be defined so that:

  - $k_i = s_i - t_i$ for $i = 0, \dots, m-1$
  - $l_i = t_{i+1} - s_i$ for $i = 0, \dots, m-2$ and $l_{m-1} = p + t_0 - s_{m-1}$
  - $K = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}k_i$
  - $L = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}l_i$
- $M = \begin{pmatrix}
  -3^{k_0} & 2^{k_1 + l_0} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
  0 & -3^{k_1} & 2^{k_2 + l_1} & \ddots & \vdots\\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
  0 & 0 & \ddots & -3^{k_{m-2}} & 2^{k_{m-1} + l_{m-2}}\\
  2^{k_0 + l_{m-1}} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -3^{k_{m-1}}
  \end{pmatrix}$
- $\Delta = 2^{K+L} - 3^K$
- $j* = \begin{cases}
  j, && \text{if }i \le j\\
  j+m, && \text{if }i > j\\
  \end{cases}$
- $\Delta M^{-1} = (m_{i,j})_{i,j}=0,1,\dots,m-1$
- $\alpha_{i,j} = \sum\limits_{h=i+1}^{j*}k_h$
- $\beta_{i,j} = \sum\limits_{h=i+1}^{j*}l_{h-1}$

**It follows that**:

- $M\begin{pmatrix}
  a_0\\
  a_1\\
  \vdots\\
  a_{m-1}
  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
  2^{l_0}-1\\
  2^{l_1}-1\\
  \vdots\\
  2^{l_{m-1}}-1
  \end{pmatrix}$
- $\det(M) = (-1)^{m-1}\Delta$
- $m_{i,j} = 2^{\alpha_{i,j}+\beta_{i,j}}3^{K-k_i-\alpha_{i,j}}$
- $m_{i,j} > 0$
- $\Delta > 0$
- $m$-cycles are in one-to-one correspondence with solutions $k_i, l_i, a_i$ of the matrix equation with $k_i, l_i, a_i$ are all positive integers.

Here is the part that I am not clear on:

- It follows that when we know upper bounds for $K$ and $L$, there are only finitely many rational solutions.

I am trying hard to understand why the above establishes that there are only finitely many solutions given $K$ and $L$.

Comment: If  K and L upper bound is known (they are bounded) than there is finite number of triplets $k_i,l_i,a_i$ which means that there is a finite number of cycles. I do not see that they claim a finite number of cycles.

Comment: @moti $K$ and $L$ are the sum iof differences in cycles.  Why would this mean a finite number of solutions?   I can see that there are only finite different m-cycles that match a given $K$ and $L$ but not why any of these m-cycle would have finite solutions.  Am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: Since a cycle is a specific mapping of a triplet and the number of potential triplets is finite, results finite number of cycles. At least this is my understanding. I think that the  key is that, to the best of my understanding, we do not have the upper bounds for K and L, thus we found a condition to assure that there is finite number of cycles but we did not prove it.

Comment: I think I am clear!  From the matrix equation, each unique combination of $k_i, l_i$ results in a unique set of $a_i$.  So, since there are finite solutions of $k_i$ and $l_i$, it follows that there is a finite set of combinations of $a_i$.   @Moti was that your point?

Comment: Yes. But note that only if there is a bound on number of possible triplet (which I have not seen in the "proof") then the number of cycles is limited. May be you will be interested also to look into some of my posting on the subject.